# Need to understand why SVG is not sized according to its contents

Tags: svg

Here is the contents of my SVG:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" b-5x9jur1f24><g b-5x9jur1f24><circle cx="10" cy="15" r="3" b-5x9jur1f24></circle>
                <text x="20" y="18" b-5x9jur1f24>My</text></g>
            <line x1="10" y1="15" x2="10" y2="35" stroke="black" b-5x9jur1f24></line></svg>
```

Why when I view the SVG in my browser does it include all of this extra white space and how do I get rid of it?  I  don't want to adjust the viewbox because it will cause the contents to become larger.

[How  is it determining my SVG is 300 x 150?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y8t8i.png)

I'm expecting the SVG to size according to its contents.

Comment: You need to change your expectations then because that's not how SVG works. 300 x 150 is the replaced element fallback size i.e. if you don't provide any size then that's what the browser defaults to.

Answer (score 1):

Either give the SVG element a viewBox attribute:

```css
svg {
  border: solid red thin;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 50 40">
  <g>
    <circle cx="10" cy="15" r="3"></circle>
    <text x="20" y="18">My</text>
  </g>
  <line x1="10" y1="15" x2="10" y2="35" stroke="black"></line>
</svg>
```

Or give the SVG element a width and a height:

```css
svg {
  border: solid red thin;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="50" height="40">
  <g>
    <circle cx="10" cy="15" r="3"></circle>
    <text x="20" y="18">My</text>
  </g>
  <line x1="10" y1="15" x2="10" y2="35" stroke="black"></line>
</svg>
```